# integral with Lebesgue and counting measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I want to compute the following integral over $S=\{ (t,t) \in \mathbb{R}^2, t \in [0,1]\} $:

$$\int_{\Bbb R} \int_{\Bbb R} \chi_S(x,y)\, d c(x)\, d \lambda(x)$$

c is the counting measure, $\lambda$ Lebesgue measure.

I know the value should be $1$. But how can I get to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>The characteristic function gives you
$$\int_{\Bbb R} \int_{\Bbb R} \chi_S(x,y)\, d c(x)\, d \lambda(x) = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 d c(x)\, d \lambda(x) $$
Now it is just a matter of how to integrate $\int_0^1 d \lambda(x)$ and $\int_0^1 d c(x)$, which follows pretty much by the definition of the respective measures.</s>

Edit: After a more careful reading of the problem, I see that $S$ is not the unit square, but the diagonal of the unit square. From this, the characteristic function should give you something like:
$$\int_{\Bbb R} \int_{\Bbb R} \chi_S(x,y)\, d c(x)\, d \lambda(x) = \int_0^1 \left( \int_{\{t\}} d c(x)\, \right) d \lambda(x)$$
An interesting observation is that the order of integration does not commute, doing $d\lambda(x)$ followed by $dc(x)$ should give you $0$.

Comment: $c([0,1] =1$ How can I get to that?

Comment: $c([0,1]) = \infty$. I misread the problem. $S$ is not the unit square, but the unit diagonal. I edited my answer.

Comment: The reason for the different values is that the measure space concerning counting meausre is not sigma-finite?

Comment: The counting measure is $σ$-finite if and only if the set $S$ is countable, and therefore not $\sigma$-finite over $[0,1]$.